# How does the Linux filesystem on Android get mapped to "Computer\PhoneName\Phone" on Windows 7?

Tags: file-system, usb-connection-mode, mount

I am trying to figure out, when I use `adb shell` I see a filesystem with directories such as `/storage/emulated/0`. When I connect my Android phone to Windows 7 I see something like the following folder: `Computer\JohnDoe(GT-I9301\Phone`.

I would like to understand how the Linux filesystem gets mounted under Windows. Does Windows mount only a specific part of the filesystem or does it reorganize everything into a new view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when connecting your device it gets mounted via [mtp](/questions/tagged/mtp). Our [mtp tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/mtp/info) gives some details on this; basically, only parts of the device's storage is exposed – usually only the SD card(s).

In easy terms, you can think of this as something similar to your "Windows Shares", where you define directories to be available over the network (with the latter being an "USB network" using MTP): Android would "hand" it the SD card as "mount point" (in case of multiple SD cards, like one internal and one "physical", that would make two items). According to the protocol, everything below that should be shown as-is, like when mounting a remote drive. I don't know how Windows is supposed to name the "entry points", but it shouldn't re-arrange things below them. Your `Computer\JohnDoe(GT-I9301)\Phone` entry most likely reflects your internal SD card (`/storage/emulated/0`).

Comment: you have pointed out the name of the protocol (MTP: Media Transfer Protocol) used on my Android device. From what I read on the tag wiki, it seems that the view that gets created groups several directories and arranges its contents in a collection (like in Windows 7 collections which are files found in different folders bunched together). What I want to know, and you haven't answered this, is how do I know what filesystem directory gets mounted into which folder on Windows 7 once I mount my device. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, Jordan – but I live in a MS free zone. I cannot tell you how Windows deals with MTP *exactly* – but it can only take what's handed to it. Android would "hand" it the SD card as "mount point" (in case of multiple SD cards, like one internal and one "physical", that would make two items). According to the protocol, everything below that should be shown as-is, like when mounting a remote drive. I don't know how Windows is supposed to name the "entry points", but it shouldn't re-arrange things below them. Your `Phone` entry most likely reflects your internal SD card (`…/emulated/0`).

Comment: Thanks. That sure helps. Perhaps add this info to your answer. Meanwhile I have accepted it. Thanks.

Comment: Good point, done that. Glad I was able to help!